# Facebook button is not showing the Liked Status if already liked

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch

Right now I am creating a facebook like custom button by changing the class of an UIbutton to **"FBSDKlikeButton"**. I have created the button and its working fine.And I am passing the path of the user which I want to like. I am navigation to that particular page,Like that particular artist and it's working fine.

The problem is that say if I am running my project again And go to that particular user which I have already liked on facebook in this case the facebbok button is showing me again **"Like"** instead of **"Liked"**. I dont know where I am doing wrong. I am pasting my code below:

this is the path I am passing in **object.ID**

```
_btnFbLike.objectID=@"http://www.musicians4rent.com/dev/artist/testextra";
```

Another thing I want to ask **how to show number of Likes** of an particular user because I am using facebook custom like button and its only showing me **Liked/Like** Status.

Comment: Did you submit your integration of the Like button for review via the Status and Review tab in the App Dashboard?

Comment: I am new to this and didn't understand what you said.Can you pls elaborate by giving an example I will be thankful to you

Comment: Open Facebook developer (https://developers.facebook.com/) website in myApp Section please select your app and then in the left hand side panel there is a section for status and review.In Select & Review section there is two tabs status and items in review. In items in review submit like button for review.

Comment: Are u sure after doing this like status will show properly. Because right now myapp is in intial condition condition and I have to implement this feature in the next version.

Comment: You can not expect the full functionality of the “native” Like button, by giving just any other arbitrary element the same class … You should use the native button, and not try to implement your own – the native one is what users are used to and what they easily recognize across different apps.

Comment: @CBroe I have tried to use the inbuilt like button provided by facebook but I was unable to resize that button . I can move it horziontally or vertically but unbale to incrase or decraese it's height and width by using CGRECt

Comment: Why do you need to resize it? Again, the way it looks is what users will instantly recognize, and that includes its dimensions – so why mess with that?

Comment: @CBore  actually i original button dimensions is not what I want that's why I was resizing it. I want a smaller facebook like button. Did you tried to resize it using Cgrect and its working on your side??